What will happen if I don't use a using block
In C# I have this code in a method:
async Task<SqlDataReader> GetSourceData()
{
    await using var sourceConnection = new SqlConnection(GetSourceConnectionString());
    await sourceConnection.OpenAsync(cancellationToken);
    var commandSourceData = new SqlCommand(GetSelectStatement(), sourceConnection);
    return await commandSourceData.ExecuteReaderAsync(cancellationToken);
}

Right now the returned reader does not work because the underlying connection is closed. I presume this is because the sourceConnection variable is disposed once I return from my GetSourceData method block.
My question is: If I remove the using statement from the line where sourceConnection is instantiated, and I don't dispose of the returned DataReader manually, will the sourceConnection ever be disposed, and if so, when?

" will the sourceConnection ever be disposed, and if so, when?" Sure it will. However it's undeterminictsic when GC will do that. Only thing you know for sure is, that i's eligable for collection when the the variable is out of scope. A using-statement makes this just deterministic in that you get more control about when that happens.

So that means there is a risk, that the connection will get disposed before I get to execute the reader and read everything from it?

Yeap, that is. You probably need to Dispose (which is what using eventually does) your connection outside the method.

^^ Or consider passing the connection to this method, so neither creation nor destruction are any of its concerns.

^^ Or the opposite: Do not return the reader but the data read. Then the complete lifetime is in scope. But that is not applicable if you need a "streaming" or deferred execution behavior.

@MakePeaceGreatAgain The document says: If the SqlConnection goes out of scope, it won't be closed.

@shingo so that would introduce a memory leak?

If not a mem leak, then a "connection leak". Which may be just as buggy. Best practice would be to use the recommended connection pooling, I guess.

@JakobS.Rames in the worst case scenario, yes.

Okay, thanks guys. I have what I need to continue. I will make sure both connection and reader are disposed properly through using blocks or manually disposing.

@shingo Yes, you're right. GC doesn't dispose nor close anything. It will just collect the object, leaving the underlying un-managed resources un-disposed.

Pass CommandBehavior.CloseConnection parameter to ExecuteReaderAsync method.

@JakobS.Rames the problem isn't so much the connection leak itself but the locks taken by the connection that remain alive while the connection is still open. That leads to increased delays in the database through blocking or defensive copying in the database, even in multi-version databases like PostgreSQL.


My question is: if I remove the using statement from the line where sourceConnection is instantiated, and I don't dispose of the returned DataReader manually, will the sourceConnection ever be disposed, and if so, when?

You want to read up about finalizers. This is a method called during garbage collection of objects to free any native resources the object owns. But even if the object is eligible for collection, there is no guarantee when the object will be collected, or if it will happen at all.
Simply removing using may not have immediate detrimental effect, but it will likely cause other issues sooner or later, like running out of connections. And issues due to undisposed objects can be difficult to find and fix. So the recommendation is to treat the finalizer as a safety net. A good thing to have, but should not be relied upon.
A better solutions would be to return the data and not the reader. Another possibility is to refactor the code to ensure the connection lifetime exceeds that of the reader, for example by changing your method to a class that disposes both the reader and connection when done.  You should also ensure the SQLCommand, and any other object implementing IDisposable is disposed. With the possible exception of Task.

will likely not have immediate detrimental effect it will, very fast, as the locks acquired by ghost connections block other queries. Especially in web applications. An orphaned connection that executed an UPDATE can end up blocking others trying to read from that table. Connection leaks are the biggest (and easiest to solve) cause for scalability issues

@PanagiotisKanavos Are you sure? I was under the impression that locks was managed at some other level. I'm fairly sure many ORMs pool the connections, and that would cause all kinds of issues if they held locks. But I agree that non disposed connections could quickly cause issues if frequently used.

Yes, they aren't managed at another level and connections are pooled by ADO.NET, not ORMs, after resetting them to clear all pending locks. If you use an explicit transaction, locks are held for the duration of the transaction. The lifecycle of locks taken outside a transaction depends on the transaction isolation level but in SQL Server it's best to assume they're kept for the duration of the connection.

@PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for the explanation! I changed the wording to "may", since, if I understand you correctly, it will depend on the type of query, how frequently queries are run etc.

When you return a SqlDataReader from a method, you transfer the responsibility for closing the connection to the caller. You do this by creating the reader with the CommandBehavior.CloseConnection option:
return await commandSourceData.ExecuteReaderAsync(
    CommandBehavior.CloseConnection, cancellationToken);

This way the connection will be closed (or more accurately returned to the ADO.NET pool) when the caller closes or disposes the reader.

If I don't dispose of the returned DataReader manually, will the sourceConnection ever be disposed, and if so, when?

In this case the connection will be disposed when the garbage collector invokes the finalizer of the connection. Until this happens, and you don't know when it will happen, the connection will stay open. Do this enough times and the connection pool maintained by the ADO.NET will be exhausted. In which case, according to the documentation:

The connection pooler satisfies requests for connections by reallocating connections as they are released back into the pool. If the maximum pool size has been reached and no usable connection is available, the request is queued. The pooler then tries to reclaim any connections until the time-out is reached (the default is 15 seconds). If the pooler cannot satisfy the request before the connection times out, an exception is thrown.

In general I would say that exposing DataReaders might increase the performance of your application (by removing the need for intermediate memory storage), but also increases the stakes by making your code more sensitive to misuse. So make sure that the potential benefits on performance justify the costs on maintainability.
